# Sytling vuejs datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs-datepicker

I am using vuejs datepicker from this [repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p92k8l717)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="">From:</label>
                <datepicker v-model="period.from" :format="period.format" :clear-button="true"
                            @selected="fetchData"></datepicker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="">To:</label>
                <datepicker v-model="period.to" :format="period.format" :clear-button="true"
                            @selected="fetchData"></datepicker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the question is I want to override some styles for the datepickerlike make it small in width and height.

[image]

Any idea how I can do that ? I tried to change the width of dropdown but that does not affect the datepicker itself!

Comment: Where is the repo link?

Comment: @samayo sorry just added it !

Comment: I use that date picker myself, but which validator are you refering to?

Comment: @samayo how do you override the styles or how you can embed it in a dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default format prop as the DatePickerFormat , it may look like what you are wanting
you can do the following

```
<datepicker v-model="period.from" :format=" DatePickerFormat" :clear-button="true"
@selected="fetchData"></datepicker>
```

if you want to add more styling over this thing , you can check my this answer too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71546906/18083887