# vuejs-datepicker change styles doesn't work

Tags: css, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs-datepicker

I'm trying to change the styles of a vuejs-datepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker)

```
 <datepicker
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   calendar-class="my_calendar"
   input-class="textfield"
   name="my_date" />
```

In the styles section I define this rule, but my datepicker **doesn't change the width**

```
.my_calendar {
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

Any idea? Or other plugin for use a datepicker in vuejs?

Thanks

Comment: `datepicker` should have a closing tag `<datepicker></datepicker>`

Comment: @RamSegev No it doesn't have to. It's self closing `<datepicker />`

Comment: Do you want the actual picker field to be 100px, or the "popup" datepicker to be 100px? I just tried this it in a codesandbox, and the "popup" is getting the new width: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sanderson-g1m23

Comment: @Djip there is nowhere in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#usage) that it is self closing, all the examples are with closing tags

Comment: @RamSegev But it doesn't matter when you aren't utilising any slots, then it's totally the same i you're doing it self-closing or not

Comment: @Djip I want change the popup. I'm watching your codesandbox and I've the same in my project, but I don't know why in my project doesn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the datepicker plugin? And are you sure that your style is loaded correctly? Where did you put the custom style you've made?

Comment: Ok, with your questions I've tried one thing and now it works. I had the style in the styles section of the component with **scoped** keyword. Removing **scope** it works correctly, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and the defaualt css does not works when it is scoped.Now,do the following steps to apply styling to Vuejs date picker and time picker

1. use input-class="--your--class--name--here " in the place of class
2. beneath your scoped style tag use another style tag which should not be scoped

`

```
    <template>
      <div>
       <datepicker
         v-model="startDate"
         input-class ="my-picker-class"
         placeholder="Start Date"
        </datepicker>       
     </div>
   </template>
    <style>
        .my-picker-class{
            border: none !important;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #F26F31 !important;
           }
    </style>
```

`
3. Here i have used my class name .my-picker-class and applied styling there , dont forget to give that "!important" at the end of the styling

Answer (score 0):

Try /deep/ to change css property from parent :

/deep/ .className {
    Css property
}

Answer (score 0):

CSS for vuejs datepicker can be passed as a prop. There are 3 props, wrapper-class, input-class and calendar class. For example

```
<datepicker input-class="rounded w-1/2" calendar-class="rounded"></datepicker>
```

**Note**: Tailwindcss classes used here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding module style. You want to add styles to `calendar-class`. So try it this way:

```
    <datepicker :class="$style.input" inputClass="input" />

    <style module>
      input {
         width: 100%;
         cursor: default;
      }
    </style>
```

**Note:** I was facing a similar issue with input class. This worked out for me.